# Spring & Hibernate: load lazy collection

Tags: hibernate, spring, lazy-loading

How do you explicitely load a lazy Object/collection?
So far I've found the only way to do this is to explicitely ask for a getter/setter of the object while it is still attached to the session: ie

```
List < Account > accounts = Bank.getAccounts();
accounts.get(i).getAccountNumber();
```

Is there another less dodgy way to do this?

I work with Spring btw, so depending on what service is being called, I want to load different collections/obkjects

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I dont think the way you are doing it is dodgy; the goal of hibernate is to be transparent.

However, there are alternatives:

1) If you want to always load the collection, you can just make the collection not lazy in the configuration.  Beware loading too much data...

2) If you want to sometimes load the collection, then leave lazy=true and add another DAO method

```
loadBankWithAccounts()
```

and either do what you are doing, with a comment about why you are initializing the collection, or use a HQL query with fetch.  Check out the documentation.

3)  Check out section 19.1.4 of the hibernate documentation, which describes how to use something like

```
Hibernate.initialize(bank.getAccounts())
```

which allows you to be more explicit with your collection initialization...

Comment: just found that there is something like Hibernate.initialize(proxy Obj), but it doesn't seem to work. where the problem occurs is with a 1-1 relation. I just do Hibernate.initialize(leerling.getFoto())

Comment: @toomuchcs i updated my answer with something that might be helpful, along the lines of what you are trying...

Comment: @toomuchcs Hibernate.initialize only initialises the simple fields, not the relationships...

Comment: @Michael Wiles: So how would I initialize another object or collection then?

Comment: like you showed in your question calling the get on the relationships. It's the same thing as an "initialise" would do in any case. That's what I've always done - works.